# Realize or Realized? Which one is correct?

Tags: tense

is it correct to say,

- I didn't realize that you were a cop.
  or
- I didn't realized that you were a cop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use *did*, it takes the simple present tense of that verb.

> I did not realize that you were a cop.